# How is $-4/7$ the slope of $4x+7y=1$?

Tags: geometry, slope

> How is $-4/7$ the slope of $4x+7y=1$?

Can someone explain? I think they have divided the coefficients of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Well, this raises the question of what the definition of a slope is.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Yes indeed divide the entire equation by $7$ to "force" $y$ to have a coefficient of $1$ and then the other terms you take them to the other side and hence you get your equation in its standard form $y=ax+b$ where $a$ is the slope of the line.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit of algebra, but essentially you have:

$4x+7y=1,$

$7y=-4x+1,$

$y=-4/7x+1/7$

the slope is always a coefficient of the term containing $x$.

Comment: FYI [MathJax formula formatting guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Speaking of algebra, what about that last $1$ in the last equation... ?

Comment: @user3733558 The 1 is called constant and if it is positive it shifts a graph in the direction of the y-axis, and if it is negative it shifts the function in the opposite direction. I recommend plotting it and play with constants in online graph software like https://www.desmos.com

Comment: If you divide the LHS by $7$, you probably need to divide *all* terms of the RHS by $7$ as well.

Comment: true, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Hints:-  For a linear equation $ax+by=c$, slop is always $-\dfrac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 0):

There’s another neat way to think about slopes. Suppose $x$ is increased by $1$ unit. How should $y$ change so that that the resulting point is still on the line, i.e. the equation remains unchanged?
The new LHS is $$4(x+1) +7y = 4x+7y +4 $$ If $y$ is decreased by $\frac 47$, the change in $x$ cancels out: $$4x+7(y-\frac 47) +4 = 4x +7y -4+4 =4x+7y $$

The slope is therefore $-\frac 47$.

Comment: So effectively solving $4(x+1)+7(y+m)=4x+7y$ for $m$. That's good for linear equations, but should note that it won't work (straightforwardly) for other functions.

Comment: @Joffan Only linear functions are in question right now.

Comment: Yes; it's really a cautionary note for someone who comes to your answer looking for a general slope finding insight.

Comment: @Joffan Oh, I see.